Why isn't a confidence level of anything >50% "good enough"?
I took a graduate-level stat course so I feel really dumb asking this, but I'm having trouble with the meaning behind 95% confidence. (Please be nice to me.)
I currently running an A/B test on two images for use in marketing. The test will run and collect data until it can make a decision at 95% confidence.
The current confidence rate is 76.55% where A has a click-rate of 2.5% and B is 4.55%.
Since A and B are roughly equal at 50% confidence (one design isn't shown to be better than the other), why should I wait until I'm at 95% confidence? At 50%, it shouldn't matter which design I choose and at 76.55% I'm already showing that B is performing better than A.
I guess I'm failing to understand why I can't make the call now. If it were testing in a pharmaceutical situation, such as a medication in a live or die scenario, I feel like I should wait for 95%, but for something as low stakes as an image choice...

What do you mean by 95% confidence here? I thought perhaps you were referring to a 95% confidence interval around your estimates, but the way you're describing it I am not sure that's what you're referring to. Also, where did you get "76.55%" and what do you mean by "current confidence rate"?

Hi Melanie. Agreeing with JElder, I would urge you to expand your terminologies a bit and I was initially of the impression that you were talking about confidence interval.

@JElder The software I'm using calls it "confidence level": https://i.sstatic.net/dX0DV.png

I think you are talking about bayesian credible intervals, which has been used by AB testing providers. I would advise you to read https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-run-an-ab-test.html and the follow up posts.

I would also suggest you don't understand the meaning of a t-test: what is the probability of having such a large difference, assuming that the two images have the same click-rate. so '76.55% confidence' means that there is a 1 in 4 chance of having such a result with no actual difference in click-rate.  I think most people would want a higher threshold ( but 95% is arbitrary - it's just a relatively intuitive level - 1 in 20)

could you also add the text to the link'What is statistical significance'

The linked image from the software in your earlier comment says that "test will run until statistical significance is achieved". This looks very very dodgy and suggests to me that this software and what it does should not be used and not be trusted. (Note that if they know that significance will at some point be achieved, they know that there is an effect, and if they really knew that, a test wouldn't be needed in the first place.)

The standard for claiming a discovery in particle physics is 5 sigma... So it's really contextual. In such a low-stakes scenario, I'd be happy with whatever the result is regardless of the confidence level after letting the test run for a couple of days.

@ChristianHennig I think you have it backwards. The test will continue to add data points until it can provide a significance level. There is no assumption that it can hit that level, only that it wont stop until it does. This is exactly what you would want. Its basically saying the software wont end the test early and provide something incomplete or incomprehensible. It says it will continue to add more data to the test until it can provide that 95% confidence, which is a measure of the data it has, not what it is testing.

@DavidS And will it take sequentiality appropriately into account?

@ChristianHennig Just saying "test will run until statistical significance is achieved" is not the red flag you're calling it out to be. Its telling you what stops the test. Its an end condition. Its a little confusing to apply so many other assumptions based on that end condition. They know there is an effect to test for, and significance in the results, because that is what the specialized testing software was built to find. Almost as confusing as complaining that a tuning fork knows your piano is out of tune, or that a multi-meter knows there is a voltage to find.

@DavidS Well, it didn't say "note that significance might never happen". At the very least that's dodgy communication. But of course you are free to use and trust that software as much as you want.

@ChristianHennig Well, if they are not accounting for the sequential testing properly, significance is guaranteed to occur eventually...

@mkt ...yes, and then meaningless.

"But why 95%? It was set by the father of modern statistics himself, Sir Ronald Fisher ... In 1925, Fisher picked 95% because the two-sided z-score of 1.96 is almost exactly 2 standard deviation .... This threshold has since persisted for almost a century."

"The test will run and collect data until it can make a decision at 95% confidence."--obligatory XKCD

You are totally correct that there is nothing "special" about the standard of 95% confidence, which is in many ways just a sort of historical artifact: statisticians have been using "95%" as the standard for a long time and so it serves as a common "default" value. But lots of times it makes sense to use a different standard of statistical significance, either higher (99.9%) or lower (80%). This is considered good practice as long as you decide on your standard before you actually do your statistical analysis (otherwise you could just choose whatever standard makes the result you got significant), and as long as you communicate this clearly to the reader (so they don't think that a result that was significant at 70% confidence was actually significant at 95% confidence).
The "make a decision beforehand" part is really important. As other posts note, deciding on a standard of significance after running an analysis (or collecting new data until you get a significant result) is a form of "moving the goalposts" and undermines the entire logic of significance testing, for complex reasons involving the underlying (frequentist) logic of these tests.
However, to decide what standard to use you need to think about what, in the context of the research question you are asking, your "tolerance" is for two different types of error. In statistics (like most things) we want to avoid being wrong, but when we make a claim that "these two things are different from one another" (which is the claim that a significance test is investigating) there are two very different ways of being wrong:
The first way we could be wrong is if we shout to the world "hey, these two things are different!" when, in reality, they are not actually different. This is called a "type 1" error (a "false positive").
The second way we could be wrong is if we say "I don't have enough information to know whether these two things are different" when, in actuality they are. This is called a "type 2" error (or a "false negative").
Note that if I actually did claim "these two things are NOT different" and they were, that would be a type 1 error. Type 1 error is about saying something incorrect, and a type 2 error is about failing to say something correct.
Science in general (not just statistics) has taken the philosophical position that type 1 errors are much much worse than type 2 errors. In other words, if we tell something to the public we want to be really confident that we're not wrong, but we are much more willing to say "we don't know" even if we have a strong hunch.
Why this matters is that the confidence level we set reflects our relative tolerance for type 1 vs type 2 errors. Put simply (and technically incorrectly, but I will complexify this in a second) a 95% confidence level means that we are willing to accept a type 1 error 5% of the time. Raising our confidence level to 99% reduces our probability of getting a type 1 error to 1% but in the same way it dramatically increases our chance of making a type 2 error. Reducing our confidence level (to 80% or 70%) means we have a larger tolerance for type 1 errors (it's OK if they happen  20% or 30% of the time) but makes it less likely that we will make a type 2 error.
So where you set your confidence levels should depend on these factors. In a medical trial where you only want to give people a drug if you are super duper sure it works, you probably want a high level of confidence, but if you are just A/B testing a message for an advertising campaign then a type 1 error isn't so bad, and you really just need to make a decision, so a lower confidence level makes sense.
However, there are a number of reasons why setting our confidence level at 50% (or 51%) is probably not a good idea. Chief among these is a fact that I have been thus far avoiding, which is that a statistical test only tells you how "confident" you can be in avoiding a very particular type of error: the error associated with generalizing from a random sample to the population from which that sample is drawn. If a result is significant at 95% confidence and it really was drawn from a perfectly random sample, then all you can be "95% confident" about is that the result is not an artifact of sampling error. But it still could be wrong for all sorts of other reasons: omitted variable bias, measurement error, or simply that you didn't actually have a perfectly random sample. Those other problems could be just as serious but there is no way to quantify them like sampling error. So for this reason the results of statistical tests at a given level of confidence are really a "lower bound" on the likelihood of type 1 error you can expect for your result.
This is part of the reason why we generally set confidence levels pretty high: 95%, 99%, or even 99.9%. You could go down to 80% or 70% if you have a really high tolerance for type 1 error due to sampling in your research question, but especially given that your results could still be biased or wrong for other reasons, going all the way down to 50% seems to me like an abandonment of the general scientific principle that we only want to say something if we're "pretty darn sure" it's correct. But that's a philosophical position, not a mathematical one.

Well said, useful to think about alpha as a sort of tradeoff for how bad you consider a Type I vs Type II error. Also useful to note that the null hypothesis is usually the "status quo" and the alternative is some change that's being proposed, which will usually come with some cost to implement - the new drug will be more expensive, the new webpage will require manpower to publish, etc. You might be willing to "take a shot" on a totally free change that has a 50% chance of improvement, but you'd want much higher confidence when the change is expensive.

What happens if we publish a Type 1 error: https://xkcd.com/882/
You do enough tests, you expect to get Type 1 errors.

Your wording is ambiguous, but 'confidence' is usually used in statistics as part of 'confidence interval', which is a way to communicate our level of uncertainty in a parameter. For historical reasons, 95% and 99% confidence intervals are the defaults we use. If the 95% confidence interval of some parameter (such as a mean, or a difference between means) excludes zero, we treat this as reasonably strong evidence that the parameter value is different from zero and term this difference 'statistically significant'. But we can, if we wish, construct a confidence interval for any value between 0 and 100% (not including exactly 0 and 100).
Importantly, taking a decision/action should involve more than the parameter estimate and associated uncertainty. The costs and benefits of the decision must be taken into account. I require less evidence to be persuaded to change my toothbrush brand than to have a limb removed. So in principle, your point about needing less evidence for a branding/advertising exercise than for a medical procedure is correct.
However, there's an additional complication here. A/B testing is a case where it is possible in principle to stop and analyse the data at any stage, and decide whether to collect more data. This seems like it should be an advantage, but this 'optional stopping' introduces major statistical biases, described here and in other threads: Why does collecting data until finding a significant result increase Type I error rate? . The approach you are following - running the test till the results are significant - seems to me guaranteed to introduce bias. If you follow this naïve approach on randomly generated data, you will with probability 100% eventually get confidence intervals that indicate that one set of random data is better than the other set of random data. There are ways to adjust for this bias statistically so that we still get accurate results, which I would encourage you to look into. But the simpler solution is to just decide in advance that you will not analyse the data till you have collected a specific number of samples (say 1000).

I actually tell my students that they can get 0% and 100% confidence intervals; the observed statistic $\hat \theta$, and $(-\infty,+\infty)$, just to provoke some thinking; I realized that students who get the "joke" understand CI's.

Your question is quite topical for me, as I had just been making my own enquiries after coming across this terminology. Don't be concerned you don't know what it means (I'm glad that it is not being taught in grad school as it seems dubious). Earlier this week, I asked an A/B software provider what he was referring to when the software reported this "confidence" value, how was it calculated, and what was its justification.
He wrote: "ten years ago when I started my journey in A/B testing almost everyone was talking about confidence (1 minus the p-value), and almost nobody talked about or understood p-values proper."
He also wrote: "As for why it is called "confidence" and to what it applies, it is the confidence level at which, if one were to construct a relevant confidence interval, said interval would not cover the null hypothesis with the data at hand. It is the flip side of the p-value through the duality of p-values and frequentist intervals."
That justification immediately raises a few red flags, but at least you know the testing will stop if the p-value reaches 5% or less.
Regarding what is an appropriate level. The software should let you vary the significance level appropriate to the costs and benefits involved: it's a context-dependent choice for the researcher/business.
Regarding stopping early, p-values should be adjusted for 'peeking' (sequential testing). Thus, you should check if the software does this to avoid bias (the provider I contacted specialized in this aspect).
Finally, for the curious-minded reader, after checking some references, I believe that the source of the software's unjustified confidence claim as 1 - p-value seems to be the relatively-recent Confidence Distributions literature.

"I believe that the source of the software's unjustified confidence claim as 1 - p-value seems to be the relatively-recent Confidence Distributions literature." All I know from that literature wouldn't license such terminology, but of course I don't know everything.

@ChristianHennig I was surprised too. However, the well-known 2016 text of Schweder and Hjort even calls it a lemma:
"Lemma 3.2 (Confidence and p-values) The confidence of the statement ‘ψ ≤ ψ0’ is the degree of confidence C(ψ0) for the interval (−∞,ψ0], and is equal to the p-value of a test of H0 : ψ ≤ ψ0 versus the alternative H1 : ψ >ψ0. The opposite statement ‘ψ > ψ0’ has confidence 1 − C(ψ0). " (p. 60)

@ChristianHennig (cont.) The consensus from a large number of studies in recent years is that p-values like 0.03 and 0.04 constitute only weak evidence against the null. The lemma, were it to be correct, would mean that a p-value of 0.03 means 97% confidence in the alternate hypothesis and 3% confidence in the null. That would not be weak evidence.

@ChristianHennig Our gut instincts should also make us wary of the lemma. Given that the p-value can be regarded as a measure of the compatibility of the data with one hypothesis (the null), it can be also described as a measure of the absolute plausibility of the null hypothesis. How is it possible that a measure of absolute plausibility can magically morph into a measure of relative plausibility?

That is in line with people who say "I'm 95% confident that the true value is between x and y" for an {x,y]-95% confidence interval, so it makes some sense... one could also just say it's a mathematical definition and it doesn't mean more than what it's defined to mean. But of course people would think that this is the real life meaning of "confidence" and that's the problem... (arguably one could say this about classical confidence intervals already).

@ChristianHennig As a frequentist, I would have to disagree with you there. From a frequentist perspective, for a 95% confidence interval procedure, we say we are 95% confident in the observed interval in the sense that the random confidence interval procedure produces intervals that cover the true value 95% of the time. There is no equivalent way to justify the confidence values in lemma 3.2.  Hence the use of the word confidence in the lemma is unjustified. David R Cox warned of the dangers involved in using confidence distributions for inference both in the 1974 Cox and Hinkley text, and

@ChristianHennig (cont) .... in his 2006 book “Principles of Statistical Inference”. In the latter book, he writes that confidence/fiducial distributions cannot in general be used to evaluate the chance that a parameter “exceeds some given constant, for example zero. This is clearly illegitimate in the present context.” (p.66).

If I understand things right, the confidence distribution allows to construct a valid frequentist confidence set at any level, i.e., if you specify the confidence level $\beta$ in advance, and then you happen to observe $x$ so that $C(x)=\beta$, $(-\infty,x]$ is a valid CI at level $\beta$ (assuming things are set up in the right way, i.e., one-sided). The confidence distribution generates confidence sets at any level, and therefore doesn't need a pre-specification of $\beta$, although of course you need one if you want to compute error/coverage probabilities.

By the way, I object to "we are 95% confident that the true parameter is in $[a,b]$" on grounds that this reads like a psychological statement that has no place in science, I'm not sure who "we" is, and I'm certainly not part of it, as I believe that no parametric model is ever "true", and consequently there is no such thing as a "true parameter" in reality. No way am I confident that it is in any interval.

@ChristianHennig Fair enough, we accept the limitations of the model being only  model. It would be better to say: Under the model, there is 95% confidence that the observed interval covers the true value in the sense that the random confidence interval procedure produces intervals that cover the true value 95% of the time. Regarding "there is no such thing as a true parameter in reality", I agree but there can be a true value (e.g. average height in a population) that we investigate using a model with a parameter for its mean. So one value of that parameter can equal the true mean.

First, let me say that the fact that "The test will run and collect data until it can make a decision at 95% confidence" is fundamentally flawed and will never give you a valid result. I point you to 2 posts on CV, here and here, with excellent answers, simulations, etc. Please read them carefully (or have your colleagues read them carefully). This is an unfortunately common practice, which should be strongly discouraged.
Because of the flaws with this repeated testing (correlation in p-values, multiple comparisons), you can not trust any result you get from it (see simulation in above posts), whether at the 95%, 75% or any other confidence level. And correcting for multiple comparisons will address one issue, but not the issue of correlated p-values.
Having said this, as previous answers have already explained very well, there is nothing "magical" about the 95% confidence level. Except that it is the safe level; no one will bat an eye if you use it. If you use a higher level many will wonder why you felt that was necessary (including me, suspecting you discovered, after the fact, that the result would still be significant at that higher confidence level), and if you use a lower one, even more will become suspicious, because you lowered the bar. So, tradition has made it so that 95% confidence raises no suspicion, and so most everyone uses it, for most tests. Having said this, it is not a bad choice, and it serves us well. So it stays a respected tradition.
In my field (medical devices), I use 99% sometimes, for tests related to safety and/or reliability, when a failure could result in a loss of life (I would not sleep too well at night with -only- a 95% confidence). But when it comes to reading comprehension (of the user instructions), or non-critical usability testing, or A/B testing of UX designs, or marketing materials, I have used 80% or 75% most of the time. Fwiw, FDA seems to accept 80% for most general usability testing, but starts to groan when you get to 75%. But I however still would use 95% for most tests, because tradition (and the fact that I will not need to explain myself).

I'm an historian of philosophy, and as such, fairly well-read in the realm of epistemology. Evidence, Proof, Truth, Justification are all matters of epistemology, so I may have something useful to add to this conversation.
The tradition has been preoccupied with the ideal of Certainty since the Greeks at least. The middle ages and Modern periods of philosophy took Certainty to be a gold standard for knowledge, and many philosophers have spilled much ink attempting to establish universal rational standards for certain knowledge. Prior to the Postmodern period, "self-evident truths" such as the "Necessary Being" of a "self-evident God" served as a foundation for further evidence and proof of truth.
However, with the industrial revolution and the rapid development of mathematical modelling, intellectuals increasingly came to appreciate the value of applying math in all matters of knowledge. At this point, one might justifiably assume that mathematical modeling has reached to every corner of verifiable knowledge. However, the question you raise does show us how the effort to dogmatically apply math to all knowledge undermines our intuitions about certainty, or at least, justifiable judgement.
A 95% probability standard is only slightly better than a 94% standard, and yet slightly less valuable than a 96% standard. The point being, the choice of 95% probability as a goal is somewhat arbitrary, and only presents as "likely", rather than "certain". As such, it reflects the Postmodern tendency to treat absolute certainty with suspect skepticism, while at the same time, requiring that our theses stand upon evidence that are not closer to an arbitrary choice than to something certain. Furthermore, as the language of mathematical certainty is most appropriate to arithmetical inferences, our application of such to empirical circumstances is naturally less certain.
Anyhow, there is much more to be said on this, but if you are looking for some good resources on epistemology, you can read Bertrand Russell or Karl Popper on the subject.

Thank you for your post.  It doesn't answer the question, though, and seems like it would be more appropriate on a philosophy forum than here.

Related to your post, an anonymous author is credited with the following statement: "Being a statistician means never having to say that you are certain". Those who do not deeply understand this will never become "good" statisticians. Statisticians have to deal with fundamental, irreducible uncertainty, and have to come to peace with this fact.

Thanks for the interesting answer. I have to admit I had a different view of the relationship between statistical uncertainty and postmodernist conceptions of knowing. For instance, in Statistics, even though we can never be sure with a particular finite dataset, the 95% CI gets tighter and tighter as we collect more data. By contrast, for a postmodernist defender of say, standpoint epistemology, certain knowledge is simply inaccessible to certain people, and there isn't even an asymptotic hope of knowing. I'm just a statistician though, and would be interested in your take!

PS don't take the downvotes too personally; we have a pretty bad case of STEM superiority syndrome around here.

A quote from the image you linked in the comments:

Based on the total number of Impressions and Clicks, we are 84.67% sure that your Variation will perform better than the Original.

This wording is a very Bayesian wording.  It reads like betting odds.  Rounding slightly, it says that if we were to place a wager on whether your Variation is better, the algorithm designers would recommend taking a bet at the odds of "win \$2 if its better, lose \$8 if it is worse" but would not recommend taking the same bet at the odds of "win \$1 if its better, lose \$9 if its worse." (rounding here to the nearest 10% for readability).
This whole marketing setup reads like a 3-armed bandit problem.  You can run another iteration of the test, with some click-through/profit rate, switch to the new image, or switch back to the old one.  The one tweak to this problem is that if you keep doing the testing, you inform your Bayesian inference problem further.
If you are not confident either way (A may be better or B may be better), then it doesn't hurt to run the test.  So low confidences encourage running the test further.  I presume that the software is smart enough that if your Variant is doing much worse than the Original (e.g. 95%), then it stops the test as well.
This is now a business decision.  Which approach leads to the most revenue.  The correct path depends on the business you are in.  Consider that these tests are not truly independent identically distributed tests.  Ideally they are close, but the images associated with a brand do affect the brand over time.  If one puts a culturally taboo image in the advertisement, it may not only affect that one click through opportunity, but permanently shape the image of your brand.
The phrasing on the tool states "Test will run until Statistical Significance is achieved."  This sounds like an automated system.  If the tool reaches 95% confident, it will automatically make a business decision for you regarding the advertisement.  This should hopefully be tunable.  I expect a seller of encyclopedias has different standards than someone who is trying to catch in on the latest flash in the pan craze.  The latter might accept something closer to 50%.
But in the end, its just betting odds.  Your company is willing to make some bets based on some information at some odds.  It does appear those were set for you at 95%.  (Incidentally, I could see such automated software being more loose regarding confidence in the other direction.  If the Variant is performing worse than the Original at, say, a 60% confidence, they might choose to yank the ad early to limit risk associated with those non independent identically distributed assumptions.)
